# Georeference IMG file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, satellite, erdas-imagine

I have a problem: I'm trying to georeference a satellite image (ASTER, ERDAS Imagine file *.img) in QGIS. I have georeferenced with QGIS before and never had any problems. The file is georeferenced already in UTM 17N WGS 84 but very, very badly, so I need to re-do it.

I have opened the file in QGIS and set the project coordinate system to UTM 17 N, then I have added a basemap with OpenLayers and used the basemap (Bing Maps) to generate GCPs using the Georeferencer tool. I set the output coordinate system to UTM 17 N, too.

Everything looks good, but when I finish the georeferencing, the file ends up in the wrong place (or in no place at all rather, the basemap disappears when I zoom to the layer). Sometimes it doesn't even display. I have tried different coordinate systems, re-sampling methods, also saved the file as .tiff - no changes. I have tried it with other raster files, they always worked well. Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

(Just in case: I have tried with ArcGIS, that doesn't work because I don't have a BingMap access key and the basemap I can access has a worse resolution than my ASTER image. Same problem in ERDAS, theoretically I could use Google Earth for georeferencing there but I'm using a computer at my university and the Google Earth tool isn't working).

I'd be very, very glad if anybody has a suggestion, this is for my bachelor thesis and quite important, and I've spent two days already trying... :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Bing Maps with openlayers plugin, the **project** projection **must be** EPSG:3857. When georefrencing by adding control points from the canvas, the target projection of the raster must have the **same** projection.

If you want UTM 17N, you have to reproject the georeferenced image in a second step with `Raster -> Projection -> Transform`.

Comment: I tried, but even with the project projection being EPSG:3857 there's no change - the raster image doesn't georeference properly. It ends up some 900.000 km to the north-west and the image seems to be scaled down to a large degree, so that the basemap doesn't display anymore because the zoom factor is too large.

Comment: project AND target projection being EPSG:3857, of course.

Comment: It seems that there was a problem with the image having a geographical reference. I now used ArcGis, via the Catalog I deleted the geographical reference (UTM 17N) for the image, after that it worked. I didn't try in QGis but I guess it should work there, too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was a problem with the image having a geographical reference already. I now used ArcGis, via the Catalog I deleted the geographical reference (UTM 17N) for the image, after that it worked. I didn't try in QGis but I guess it should work there, too.

Comment: In fact I am now trying again in QGis, and I have the same problem. It simply doesn't work, and these are the only files it doesn't work with. Any further ideas?